# SQL and VB.NET : SELECT query using data in textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, radio-button

I'm trying to create a search, where the SQL query depends on a radio button and a textbox.

```
SELECT * FROM [Sales] WHERE (text in radio button) = (text in textbox)
```

How can I implement this?

Below is my full code.

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    If radClient.Checked = True Then
        Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim provider As String
        Dim source As String
        provider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        source = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|DeltaOneMDB.mdb"
        connection.ConnectionString = provider & source
        GridView1.Visible = False
        connection.Open()
        SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE ClientID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
        connection.Close()
    ElseIf radItem.Checked = True Then
        Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim provider As String
        Dim source As String
        provider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        source = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|DeltaOneMDB.mdb"
        connection.ConnectionString = provider & source
        GridView1.Visible = False
        connection.Open()
        SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE ItemID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
        connection.Close()
    ElseIf radUser.Checked = True Then
        Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim provider As String
        Dim source As String
        provider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        source = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|DeltaOneMDB.mdb"
        connection.ConnectionString = provider & source
        GridView1.Visible = False
        connection.Open()
        SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE UserID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
        connection.Close()
    ElseIf radUser.Checked = False And radClient.Checked = False And radItem.Checked = False Then
        ErrorLabel.Text = "Error: You have not chosen a search criteria."
    End If
End Sub
```

The table, textbox and radio button are all on the same form. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Web, and trying to change the data source for a GridView object on the form. However, I keep getting the error:

***The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.***

Apologies for not giving my code earlier.

Thank you!

Comment: What have yout tried so far?

Comment: Really you should start giving some code where you are stopped. To help we need a context, names of controls, code already written, error messages. This question is so vague that will be closed.

Comment: Just out of interest, how do you get the text into the radio button in the first place?  Also, I'm not sure if I've got this right, but you're comparing the text from the radio button to the text from the text box?  Is one of these text elements a field in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code I see a lot of unnecessary lines. I wish to give you an example of what I think you could do to simplify your code. 
First, remove the code not needed for the SqlDataSource (I suppose that you have already opened the connection with the database and however this could be done just one time at click entry.
Second, in each switch prepare the command to be executed and the parameter (name and value) to pass for that command
At the end update your SqlDataSource and rebind everything

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    Dim prm as String
    Dim prmValue as String

    prmValue = txtSearch.Text
    If radClient.Checked = True Then
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE ClientID = @clientID"
        prm = "@clientID"
    ElseIf radItem.Checked = True Then
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE ItemID = @itemID"
        prm = "@itemID"
    ElseIf radUser.Checked = True Then
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE UserID = @userID"
        prm = "@userID"
    ElseIf radUser.Checked = False And radClient.Checked = False And radItem.Checked = False Then
        ErrorLabel.Text = "Error: You have not chosen a search criteria."
        return
    End If
    SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = sqlQuery
    SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Add(prm, prmValue)
    SqlDataSource3.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve! However I got an error on your previous to last question:

Error 1 'Parameters' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource'.

Comment: Thanks again, @Steve! need your help with one last thing please! I'm stuck with one issue that won't solve itself, the following error: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: I suppose that you have to set the ConnectionString property of the SqlDataSource3 to something. Perhaps when your create the SqlDataSource somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

when using SQLDatasource, you dont have to specify Connections, it manages its own connection.

what you need to do is:

1. Update the Select Statement based on the Radio Button Status
2. Call the DataSource DataBind Function `SqlDataSource3.DataBind()`

Also, Better Approach is Using Stored Procedure that allow Null Values.
better for SQL Injection (Threats for your Database)

```
SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE (@ClientID IS NULL OR ClientID = @ClientID)
AND (@ItemID IS NULL OR ItemID = @ItemID )
AND (@UserIDIS NULL OR UserID= @UserID)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Muhammad, jazak allah khair! However, may I please know how to update the SQL Select statement? Did I do it wrong?

Comment: You are most welcome, wa jazak.
in your current select, you allow a statement to have something like 'Where ClientID = '--DUMMY ; DROP DATABASE ABC;'
SQL Injection is about executing statements that are based on user input, that may harm your application/servers through some hacks.
Stored Procedures are Safer, it blocks SQL Injections

Answer (score -1):

HORRIBLE SOLUTIONS everywhere on internet. This is probably the simplest in the world.

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.print("&lt;html>");
        out.print("&lt;body>");
        out.print("&lt;form>");
        out.print("&lt;textarea rows='5' columns='500' name='t1'>&lt;/textarea>");
        //out.print("&lt;input type='text' name='t2'>");
        //out.print("c&lt;input type='checkbox' value='c' name='t1'>");
        //out.print("d&lt;input type='checkbox' value='d' name='t1'>");
        out.print("&lt;input type='submit' value='execute' name='b1'>");
    //  out.print("&lt;input type='submit' value='show' name='b1'>");
        //out.print("&lt;input type='submit' value='query' name='b1'>");

        String a,c;
        a=request.getParameter("t1");
        //b=request.getParameter("t2");
        c=request.getParameter("b1");
        if(c!=null)
            {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saransh","root","");
                Statement st=con.createStatement();

                if(a.startsWith("delete"))
                {
                    out.print("<br>");
                    out.print("delete query execution...");         

                    //st.executeUpdate("insert into student2(name,address) values('"+a+"',"+b+"')") ;
                    st.executeUpdate(a);
            }

                else if(a.startsWith("select"))
                {   out.print("<br>");
                    out.print("select query execution...");         
                    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(a);
                    ResultSetMetaData m1=rs.getMetaData();
                    out.print("<br>");
                    for(int i=1;i<=m1.getColumnCount();i++)
                    {String x1=m1.getColumnLabel(i);
                    out.print("   "+x1);}
                    out.print("<br>");//name of label               
                    while(rs.next())
                {   String s0=rs.getString("Stu_roll");
                    String s1=rs.getString("name");
                    String s2=rs.getString("address");

                out.print(s0+"   "+s1+"   "+s2);
                    out.print("<br>");  
                    }}

                else if(a.startsWith("insert"))
                {   out.print("<br>");
                out.print("insert query execution...");         

                    st.executeUpdate(a);
                }

                else if(a.startsWith("drop"))
                {   out.print("<br>");
                out.print("drop query execution...");           

                    st.executeUpdate(a);
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                out.print(e);
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            }


        out.print("&lt;/form>");
        out.print("&lt;/body>");
        out.print("&lt;/html>");
```

remove commented lines. only problem is that queries are case sensitive. You can figure out what string operation to use to make it 'ignore case'.